# Prepared Statements not working in mySQL / PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

For some reason I keep getting this error when attempting to run prepared query with `mysqli`

> mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match
>   number of fields in prepared statement

This db class works fine until I try to use a query with `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

I'm wondering if anyone knows why?  I'll post the query, schema, etc.. below.

NOTE:  I saw one question on here that suggested I specifically spell out all the field names I want to select, rather than use **'*'**(star).  There are A LOT of fields involved and I spent almost an hour typing them all out.  When I tested, it didn't change anything.  I have omitted that and returned to using star just in case anyone was going to suggest I type them all out.   Already tried. Doesn't help.

ALSO: This query works fine if I put it straight into phpMyAdmin, so it's a working query.  Just throwing an error when trying to bind the result for some reason.   Even if I remove the multiple joins and just have one left join it still throws the error about not having the correct parameter count.   I don't get it.

### Query Output by PHP

```
SELECT * FROM `SlipMaster` 
left outer join `SlipMain` 
    on `SlipMaster`.`slipCode` = `SlipMain`.`slipCode` 
left outer join `ContractMain` 
    on `SlipMain`.`slipContractId` = `ContractMain`.`id` 
left outer join `ClientMain` 
    on `SlipMain`.`slipClientId` = `ClientMain`.`id` 
left outer join `PaymentMain` 
    on `ContractMain`.`contractPaymentId` = `PaymentMain`.`id` 
left outer join `VesselMain` 
    on `SlipMain`.`slipVesselId` = `VesselMain`.`id` 
WHERE 1 = ?
```

### PHP CODE USING MYSQLI DB CLASS

```
    $from = '
        `SlipMaster` 
        left outer join `SlipMain` 
            on `SlipMaster`.`slipCode` = `SlipMain`.`slipCode` 
        left outer join `ContractMain` 
            on `SlipMain`.`slipContractId` = `ContractMain`.`id` 
        left outer join `ClientMain` 
            on `SlipMain`.`slipClientId` = `ClientMain`.`id` 
        left outer join `PaymentMain` 
            on `ContractMain`.`contractPaymentId` = `PaymentMain`.`id` 
        left outer join `VesselMain` 
            on `SlipMain`.`slipVesselId` = `VesselMain`.`id`';
    $dbi->new_query();
    $dbi->add_param('i', '1');
    $dbi->select($from, '*', '1=?');
```

### PHP MYSQLI DB CLASS

```
<?php

class mysqliObject {

    public $user = "";
    public $pass = "";          
    public $name = "";
    public $host = "";
    public $_db;
    public $_config;
    public $MYSQLI_LINK = FALSE;
    public $rows = FALSE;
    public $last_error = FALSE;
    public $last_query = FALSE;
    public $result = FALSE;
    public $last_id = FALSE;
    public $paramTypeArray = [];
    public $paramBindArray = [];


    public function __construct() {
    }

    public function __destruct() {

            $this->close();
    }

    public function connect() {

            $this->host = $this->_config->get('DBHOST');
            $this->name = $this->_config->get('DBNAME');
            $this->user = $this->_config->get('DBUSER');
            $this->pass = $this->_config->get('DBPASS');
            $this->MYSQLI_LINK = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->name);
    }

    public function setDatabase($databaseConnection) {

            $this->_db = $databaseConnection;
    }

    public function setConfig($config) {

            $this->_config = $config;
    }

    public function close() {

            @mysqli_close($this->MYSQLI_LINK);
    }

    public function get_hash($p) {
            return password_hash($p, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 10)); 
    }

    public function check_password($p, $h) {
            return (password_verify($p, $h)) ? true : false;
    }

    public function get_rndkey($length=32) {

        $random_string="";
        while(strlen($random_string)<$length && $length > 0) {
                $randnum = mt_rand(0,61);
                $random_string .= ($randnum < 10) ?
                        chr($randnum+48) : ($randnum < 36 ? 
                                chr($randnum+55) : $randnum+61);
         }
        return $random_string;
    }

    public function escape($value) {

            return mysqli_real_escape_string($this->MYSQLI_LINK, $value);
    }

    public function get_lastid() {

            return $this->MYSQLI_LINK->insert_id;
    }

    public function new_query() {

            $this->paramTypeArray = Array();    
            $this->paramBindArray = Array();    
    }

    public function add_param($t, $d) {

            $this->paramTypeArray[] = $t;
            $this->paramBindArray[] = $d;
    }


    // Shortcut for Select Method          
    public function s($t,$x, $d, $w) {
            $this->new_query();
            foreach($d as $v) {
                $this->add_param($v['t'], $v['v']);
            }
            return $this->select($t, $x, $w) ? $this->result : false;
    }

    public function select($t, $d, $c) {

            /* Types: s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob */
            $a_params = array();

            $param_type = '';
            $n = count($this->paramTypeArray);
            for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
                    $param_type .= $this->paramTypeArray[$i];
            }

            $a_params[] = & $param_type;

            for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
              $a_bind_params[] = $this->paramBindArray[$i];
            }

            for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
              $a_params[] = & $a_bind_params[$i];
            }

            $q = 'SELECT '.$d.' FROM '.$t.' WHERE '.$c;
            $s = $this->MYSQLI_LINK->prepare($q);

            if($s === false) {
              trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $q . ' Error: ' . $this->MYSQLI_LINK->errno . ' ' . $this->MYSQLI_LINK->error, E_USER_ERROR);
            }

            call_user_func_array(array($s, 'bind_param'), $a_params);

            $s->execute();


            $meta = $s->result_metadata();

            while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) { 
            $var = $field->name; 
            $$var = null; 
            $fields[$var] = &$$var;
    }


    call_user_func_array(array($s,'bind_result'),$fields);


    $i = 0;
    while ($s->fetch()) {
            $results[$i] = [];

            foreach($fields as $k => $v) {
                $results[$i][$k] = $v;
            }
            $i++;
    }

            $s->close();    

            $this->last_query = $q;


            if (count($results) > 0) {

                    $this->result = $results;
                    return TRUE;
            } else {

                    $this->last_error = mysqli_error($this->MYSQLI_LINK);
                    return FALSE;
            }

            return FALSE;
    }





    public function delete($t, $c) {

        $a_params = array();

        $param_type = '';
        $n = count($this->paramTypeArray);
        for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
            $param_type .= $this->paramTypeArray[$i];
        }

        $a_params[] = & $param_type;

        for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
          $a_bind_params[] = $this->paramBindArray[$i];
        }

        for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
          $a_params[] = & $a_bind_params[$i];
        }

        $q = "delete from ".$t." where ".$c;

        $s = $this->MYSQLI_LINK->prepare($q);

        $this->last_query = $q;

        if($s === false) {
          trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $q . ' Error: ' . $this->MYSQLI_LINK->errno . ' ' . $this->MYSQLI_LINK->error, E_USER_ERROR);
        }

        call_user_func_array(array($s, 'bind_param'), $a_params);

        $s->execute();

        $count = $s->affected_rows;

        $s->close();

        if ($count > 0) {

            $this->rows = $count;
            return TRUE;
        } else {

            $this->last_error = mysqli_error($this->MYSQLI_LINK);
            return FALSE;
        }

    }





    public function insert($t, $d) {


        $a_params = array();

        $param_type = '';
        $n = count($this->paramTypeArray);
        for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
            $param_type .= $this->paramTypeArray[$i];
        }

        $a_params[] = & $param_type;

        for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
          $a_bind_params[] = $this->paramBindArray[$i];
        }

        for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
          $a_params[] = & $a_bind_params[$i];
        }


        $query_cols = 'insert into '.$t.' (';
        $query_vals = 'values (';

        while (list($key, $value) = each($d)) {

            $query_cols .= $value . ', ';

            $query_vals .= '?, ';
        }

        $query_cols = substr($query_cols, 0, strlen($query_cols) - 2);

        $query_vals = substr($query_vals, 0, strlen($query_vals) - 2);

        $q = $query_cols . ') ' . $query_vals . ')';

        $this->last_query = $q;

        $s = $this->MYSQLI_LINK->prepare($q);

        if($s === false) {

          trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $q . ' Error: ' . $this->MYSQLI_LINK->errno . ' ' . $this->MYSQLI_LINK->error, E_USER_ERROR);
        }

        call_user_func_array(array($s, 'bind_param'), $a_params);

        $s->execute();

        $count = $s->affected_rows;
        $this->last_id = $s->insert_id;
        $s->close();

        if ($count > 0) {

            $this->rows = $count;
            return TRUE;
        } else {

            $this->last_error = mysqli_error($this->MYSQLI_LINK);
            return FALSE;
        }

    }


    public function update($t, $d, $c) {

        $a_params = array();

        $param_type = '';
        $n = count($this->paramTypeArray);
        for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
            $param_type .= $this->paramTypeArray[$i];
        }

        $a_params[] = & $param_type;

        for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
          $a_bind_params[] = $this->paramBindArray[$i];
        }

        for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
          $a_params[] = & $a_bind_params[$i];
        }

        $q = 'update ' . $t . ' set ';

        while (list($key, $value) = each($d)) {
                $q .= $value . ' = ?, ';
        }

        //strip comma off end of variable
        $q = substr($q, 0, strlen($q) - 2);

        $q .= ' where ' . $c;

        $this->last_query = $q;

        $s = $this->MYSQLI_LINK->prepare($q);

        if($s === false) {
          trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $q . ' Error: ' . $this->MYSQLI_LINK->errno . ' ' . $this->MYSQLI_LINK->error, E_USER_ERROR);
        }

        call_user_func_array(array($s, 'bind_param'), $a_params);

        $s->execute();

        $count = $s->affected_rows;

        $s->close();

        if ($count > 0) {

            $this->rows = $count;
            return TRUE;
        } else {

            $this->last_error = mysqli_error($this->MYSQLI_LINK);
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

} // End Class
```

### Simplified Schema

NOTE: Let me know if you need me to post a more complete schema.  This just shows the fields that are linking the joins.   All fields are INT(255) unique, `id` fields are INT(255) AI PRIMARY

`SlipMaster` links to `SlipMain` via `slipCode`, all others link foreign key 
 to Primary `id`

```
SlipMaster (id, slipCode)
SlipMain (id, slipCode, slipContractId, slipClientId, slipVesselId)
ContractMain (id, contractPaymentId)
ClientMain (id)
PaymentMain (id)
VesselMain (id)
```

Comment: There is a conditional clause there, but for testing I just changed to 1 = 1 so there is no question about whether the where clause is causing an issue.   Although it would seem so from the error, I believe the error is caused by something else.  Perhaps an issue w/ the DB Class as the query seems pretty straightforward to me.

Comment: Thats so much code to parse through. But to help point you in the right direction this doesn't have to do with `*`, and its doubtful that the JOINS are to blame. The error is that the number a params you are trying to bind does not equal the number of `?`s in your prepared statement. Try printing out your $a_params arrays to check what you are trying to bind.

Comment: Its just the one ? mark as shown in the query.  If I remove the joins, then the query works.   @dan08

Comment: You should debug the select method of your db class.  In particular this line:  call_user_func_array(array($s, 'bind_param'), $a_params);  Verify your assumptions at that point.

Comment: Oh shoot, I misread the error, its `bind_result` not `bind_param`. So the error is around here: `call_user_func_array(array($s,'bind_result'),$fields);`. I would run the query in the Msql console to see what the columns are, and `print_r($fields);` and make sure they match up like you think. Maybe the JOINs are adding fields that your `$meta->fetch_field()` function isn't catching. Spelling out the columns in the SELECT would help to avoid this problem.

Comment: I tried that already though.   Maybe I didn't spell out the right fields?   I'll go print_r $fields ,  but i don't have a console for sql, i just use php myadmin.   the fields returned are all fields from every table when i run the query there.   Thanks for your continued help on this.  You should post this as an answer if possible. @dan08

Comment: $Fields matches up with Column count,  I've aliased every one of them too so I'm sure there are no others.  Hmmm...

Comment: Put an `assert($meta->field_count == count($fields), sprintf("Result contains %d fields, but binding has %d fields!", $meta->field_count, count($fields)));` on the line before calling `bind_result`. The result set contains multiple columns named `id` and `slipCode`, and your `$fields` approach cannot handle them. You might want to change the keys of `$fields` to include both the table name and the column name.

Comment: Can you add the `.sql` file of your database..

Comment: I think that you need to add 2 more variables in `call_user_func_array(array($s,'bind_result'),$fields);` since in the query you are requesting 3 variables while in here you are passing only 1. Also, why do you use `$$var = null; `?

Comment: @MalikNaik Sorry I cannot, the data is sensistive.  There is a sample schema post in Q

Comment: @DCoder I did that and it says 64 and 62!  Can you post an answer showing how to fix that ??

Comment: @Stanimir You are right, see comment above.  How can I fix this?  Cant remember on the &$$var

Comment: @NotoriousPet0: Rick James already answered. The easiest approach would be to throw out this result binding thingamajig and just use `$this->results = $s->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);`, with the necessary error checking added.

Comment: @DCoder So are you saying there is no way to do this with bind_result and it must be thrown out ?  Thanks for help

Comment: I'm not saying "there's no way to do this with `bind_result`" (it's as simple as using `$var = $field->table . '_' . $field->name;` in the loop). I'm saying that as it is now, `bind_result` does not give you any tangible benefit over the simpler `fetch_all()` approach.

Comment: OK, so even if I send a query without using * , I'll still be fine with taking out the bind_result?   Sorry, I'm not too familiar with these functions,  I've been reading up on them, but it's kind of confusing. @DCoder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*` is all the fields in *all* the tables you are `JOINing` together.  This includes duplicates, such as slipCode, which exists at least twice.

Plan A:  Spell out the fields that you really want.  This will make it easier to count them and know how many to "bind".  And it will make it clear what order to bind them in.

Plan B:  Don't use `bind_result`; simply fetch the result into an array or hash.

Plan C:  Do both.  (I prefer this.)

Comment: Are there any drawbacks to not using bind_result?   How would I code that in the DB class?   Thx for your help .. .Also, I did Plan A already.  No luck.  In my actual query it is all spelled out and not using *, just too long to post in Q so put *

Comment: Sending the Upvote your way, if you can expand the answer to include how I can safely remove bind_result from the code, I will award the bounty.   (hint: see comments on Q, pretty much says it, just want anyone viewing this to not have to go digging through comments to get an answer.)  Thanks again!

Comment: Do you care about the bounty?  Can I give it to the guy w/ no rep?

Comment: You have to judge between us.  He made points I did not make and vice versa.  I don't think either of us is steering you wrong.

Comment: You answered first, but the guy could use the rep.  It's up to you if you want the 100 rep or not.   Let me know, it expires in a couple days or so.

Answer (score 2):

@Notorious, I think the answer to your problem is not the sql but to the `bind_result()` function that you are using.

Explaining furthur, the `bind_result()` function is used to assign retrieved data from the database to variables. So the number of fields selected (returned from the database) must be equal to the number of binded results.

For instance,
If I selected the firstname and the lastname fields from the database I must use

```
bind_result($firstname, $lastname);
```

So as you can see the number of variables in the `bind_result()` is equal to the number of fields selected.

For your case you are selecting everything from the first db to second to third ..blablabla till the last db. So make sure the number of fields assigned to the the `bind_result()` function is equal to the number of all the fields returned. That is the sum of the total number of columns in all the databases.

So you got a lot of typing to do but at least its for the best.

Good luck and I hope it helped.

Comment: Hey thanks, unfortunately the other guy answered before you.  But hey, if you can put a detailed code example up (see comments for question for solution involving `$this->results = $s->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);`)   and I'll award you the bounty.  Gotta do it before Rick James though.  He's laggin.  :)